# Prolog function output

Tags: lambda, prolog

I am trying to do a function in prolog to add item in a list of list. What I want to do is to add 1 item at the end of the first list, 2 item at the end of the second list, etc.

I wrote this to start:

```
changerTableau(N,[Ligne|Reste],TableauVide,NouveauTableau):-
    repeter(N,'.',Point),
    append(Ligne,Point,NouvelleLigne),
    append(TableauVide,NouvelleLigne,NouveauTableau),
    writeln(N),
    N2 is N+1,
    writeln(NouveauTableau),
    changerTableau(N2,Reste,NouveauTableau,Output).

repeter(0,_,[]):-!.
repeter(N,Item,[Item|Reste]):-
    N2 is N - 1,
    repeter(N2,Item, Reste).
```

So what I want the program to do is, if I start with that:

```
changerTableau(1,[['x','w'],['a','b'],['l','o','l']],[ ],Resultat).
```

I want to have in output:

```
Resultat = [['x','w','.'],['a','b','.','.'],['l','o','l','.','.','.']]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code contains three errors:

1. The variable `Output` is never used. You actually should have got a warning about this being a singleton variable. What you want to do is make `Output` the last argument in the head of `changerTableau/4`:

   changerTableau(N,[Ligne|Reste],TableauVide,Output):-
2. You want to construct a list of lists. However, when you append `NouvelleLigne` to `TableauVide`, you just append a list to a list, resulting in a list, not a list of lists. You need to do it like this:

   append(TableauVide,[NouvelleLigne],NouveauTableau),
3. There is no clause of `changerTableau/4` that ends the recursion. Therefore, you will always get a `no` as answer. Add this as the first clause of `changerTableau/4`:

   changerTableau(_, [], TableauVide, TableauVide).

This should get your code working, although you could simplify it to get rid of the `append` in point 2 altogether:

```
changerTableau(_, [], []).
changerTableau(N,[Ligne|Reste],[NouvLigne|NouvReste]):-
  repeter(N,'.',Point),
  append(Ligne,Point,NouvLigne),
  N2 is N+1,
  changerTableau(N2,Reste,NouvReste).
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is exactly what I am trying to do :)

Answer (score 1):

you can consider using maplist too if your system has one :

```
changerTableau([], []) :- !.
changerTableau(List, [Head|Result]) :-
    maplist(append_(['.']), List, [Head|Tail]),
    changerTableau(Tail, Result).

append_(A, B, C) :- append(B, A, C).
```

Or, with the [lambda](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl) module :

```
changerTableau([], []) :- !.
changerTableau(List, [Head|Result]) :-
    maplist(\X^Y^append(X, ['.'], Y), List, [Head|Tail]),
    changerTableau(Tail, Result).
```